# Short code with loop, function and list isn't working.Much appreciated if you help. (New at Python)

Tags: python, list, function, loops

Just started learning python, so I'm very thankful for anyone who can help.

Anyways the task is to define a function that takes a list of numbers and returns 3 values - how many positive numbers, negative numbers and zeroes there are in the list.

The main program I need to use a loop that gets the user to input however many numbers he wants (must be between 3 and 6, and this has to be checked). these numbers that the user inputs are to be added to a list. Then I have to call a function that uses the list as the argument and then print the results that the function returns.

using a loop is obligatory.

```
def three(z):
    np = 0
    nn = 0
    zeroes = 0
    
    for y in z:
        if x<0:
            nn+=1
        if x>0:
            np+=1
        if x==0:
            zeroes+=1
    
    print('there are ', np, ' positive numbers\nthere are ', nn, ' negative numbers\nthere are ', zeroes, ' zeros')
    
    return (np, nn, zeroes)

num_list = []

a = 0
n = eval(input('input a number (bigger than 3, smaller than 6): '))

while n>3 and n<6:
    if a < n:
        x = eval(input('input a number: '))
        num_list.append(x)
        a+= 1
    else:
        break
        
three(num_list)
```

I made a loop and a function, but I'm pretty sure I messed up at the loop or somewhere else because it looks like I'm using a lot of variables and it looks more complicated then it should probably be.

Comment: Never use `eval` with user input. [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Use `for _ in range(n):` to loop `n` times.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. It's already a built-in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should avoid using `eval` to get the numerical value of the user input. Ignatius Reilly left a good link to explain why in a comment. Instead, just cast the string input to int using `int(input(...))` instead.

Second, the issue is that you are comparing `x` to zero. `x` is not defined in your function, so it looks outside the function scope and then pulls what you defined as `x` there, which is the last user input from `x = eval(input(...))`. So a user that inputs `-1, 2, 0, 4` will return (4, 0, 0) because it just compares 4 to 0 four times rather than each individual input. You made a simple mistake here and should've used `y` in your `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for-in-range` loop to execute code n times.

Use `int()` to convert user input to an integer, not `eval()`.

```
n = int(input("Input a number between 3 and 6: ")
if 3 <= n <= 6:
    nums = []
    for _ in range(n):
        x = int(input("Input a number: "))
        nums.append(x)
    print(three(list))
else:
    print("That's out of the range")
```